# NetSuite Saved Search Formula Help - Return last populated field of 5 fields

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

We utilize 5 'stop' fields for routing trucks, I would like to populate the last stop in a single field on a saved search, however there are times where stop 5 isn't necessarily the last stop, sometimes there are only 4 stops or 3 or 2 or 1 stops.

I have a working formula, however I'm curious if there is a better way to handle this, here is my formula:

```
CASE WHEN {stop5} IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN {stop4} IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN {stop3} IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN {stop2} IS NULL THEN {stop1} ELSE {stop2} END ELSE {stop3} END ELSE {stop4} END ELSE {stop5} END
```

I feel like my formula is clunky and there might be a better way that I'm not aware of, any assistance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use-case for [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87), which "returns the first non-null expr in the expression list."

```
COALESCE({stop5}, {stop4}, {stop3}, {stop2}, {stop1})
```